# Wordpress- I deleted Parent Category but Child catageory still remains

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories

Hi I thought when we delete a parent category, all sub-categories will be deleted as well but that didn't remove. Is this a bug in wordpress? is there a reference we could get from wordpress that this is their implementation? Thank currently, I'm using 3.8.1 wordpress version. Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just had to do this for WooCommerce's product categories, so here it goes:

```
add_action( 'pre_delete_term', 'prefix_pre_delete_term', 10, 2 );

function prefix_pre_delete_term( $term, $taxonomy ) {

    if ( $taxonomy === 'product_cat' ) {

        $term_children = get_term_children( $term, $taxonomy );

        if ( !empty( $term_children ) ) {

            foreach ( $term_children as $term_child ) {

                wp_delete_term( $term_child, $taxonomy );

            }

        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I add a conditional to only make this behaviour happen for product categories. If you remove the taxonomy conditional, it will work for all your site's taxonomies.

If you have a lot of subcategories or items inside all the term's hierarchy, it might take a fair amount of time to end the process (execution time timeouts and memory limit exhaustion are certain possibilities).

Please note that there's no need to iterate because the hook will get executed for every `wp_delete_term()` call.

Also please note that in order for the frontend to remove the category and its subcategories when 'Delete' is clicked, some extra javascript code would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not bug, it's WordPress implementation that the child category still remains after deleting the parent category.

However, if you need to delete the child category too, you can use the WordPress hook 'delete_category' to do perform your custom action. For more info check out [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29)

Comment: Hi, is there a reference we could get from wordpress that this is their implementation? Thanks